# RestKit to Core Data Mapping creates objects of a Subentity

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping, restkit

I am using RestKit to map a JSON Response to Core Data with parent/child Entities. My problem occurs when a JSON payload of `Parent` objects is received, as they are somehow mapped to instances of the `Child` entity (which is really weird).

Let's consider the following mapping (I commented out everything else, even the child mapping):

```
RKEntityMapping *parentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[Parent entityName] inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
[parentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"remoteObjectId"}];
[parentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"title" ]];
parentMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"remoteObjectId" ];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:parentMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"Parents" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];
```

Now when I enable both Network and ObjectMapping trace logging, the following happens (note that everything is fine until the mapping operation is about to start, but then it's suddenly a `Child` object instead of the `Parent` object it should be):

```
2014-07-13 18:19:15.311 uni-hd[26579:f03] T restkit.network:RKResponseMapperOperation.m:469 Mapping HTTP response to nil target object... // can you explain this as well?
2014-07-13 18:19:15.311 uni-hd[26579:f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:377 Executing mapping operation for representation: (
        {
        id = 1;
        title = Foo;
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        title = Bar;
    }
)
 and targetObject: (null)
2014-07-13 18:19:15.311 uni-hd[26579:f03] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:320 Examining keyPath '<null>' for mappable content...
2014-07-13 18:19:15.311 uni-hd[26579:f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:297 Found mappable collection at keyPath '<null>': (
        {
        id = 1;
        title = Foo;
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        title = Bar;
    }
)
2014-07-13 18:19:15.312 uni-hd[26579:f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:229 Asked to map source object {
    id = 1;
    title = Foo;
} with mapping <RKEntityMapping:0x10a615370 objectClass=**Parent** propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10a616660 id => remoteObjectId>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10a616370 title => title>"
)>
2014-07-13 18:19:15.312 uni-hd[26579:6703] D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:131 Cached property inspection for Class '**Parent**': {
    children =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = children;
    };
    parent =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = Parent;
        name = parent;
    };
    remoteObjectId =     {
        isPrimitive = 1;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = remoteObjectId;
    };
    title =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = title;
    };
}
2014-07-13 18:19:15.312 uni-hd[26579:f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:859 Starting mapping operation...
// Why is it a Child object now?!
2014-07-13 18:19:15.313 uni-hd[26579:f03] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:860 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0x10a85d720> for '**Child**' object. Mapping values from object {
    id = 1;
    title = Foo;
} to object <**Child**: 0x10accc420> (entity: Child; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://16E53A02-12F7-4A41-B0CB-8241A694F197/Child/p1> ; data: <fault>) with object mapping (null)
2014-07-13 18:19:15.313 uni-hd[26579:f03] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:438 Found transformable value at keyPath 'id'. Transforming from class '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSNumber'
2014-07-13 18:19:15.313 uni-hd[26579:f03] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:453 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'id' to 'remoteObjectId'
2014-07-13 18:19:15.314 uni-hd[26579:f03] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:484 Skipped mapping of attribute value from keyPath 'id to keyPath 'remoteObjectId' -- value is unchanged (1)
2014-07-13 18:19:15.314 uni-hd[26579:f03] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:438 Found transformable value at keyPath 'title'. Transforming from class '__NSCFString' to 'NSString'
2014-07-13 18:19:15.314 uni-hd[26579:f03] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:453 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'title' to 'title'
2014-07-13 18:19:15.315 uni-hd[26579:f03] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:469 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'title' to 'title'. Value: Universität Heidelberg
2014-07-13 18:19:15.315 uni-hd[26579:f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:928 Finished mapping operation successfully...
(... second object mapping and end results ...)
```

So instead of mapping to a `Parent` object, a `Child` object is created.

On the server those are separate models and therefore have ids that overlap. This may (?) be relevant, although at this point there should really be no `Child` object with the same id around that could interfere because the database starts empty. Because it says `Mapping [...] to object <**Child**: 0x10accc420>` I suspect there is a `Child` object created before which then has the same `remoteObjectId` but when I do a Core Data fetch before the JSON request, the database is empty. I found [this fixed issue on Github](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1059) with a similar problem concerning connection descriptions, but it does not mention the creation of objects or the identification/mapping itself.

**How can I make sure, `Parent` objects are created instead of instances of its subentity `Child`?**

**Edit:** I found a solution for this issue using `identificationPredicate` (see answer below). Nevertheless, this is my Model:

[image: Model]

I logged the store content executing the following fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[UHDNewsCategory entityName]];
fetchRequest.includesSubentities = YES;
```

There are no objects in the store before the JSON request. Afterwards, there is a `UHDNewsSource` (=`Child`) object for every `UHDNewsCategory` (=`Parent`) in the server response.

Comment: Show a picture of your model. Can you also log the entire contents of the data store before and after your test?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue, but it don't think the default RestKit implementation works as intended here.

Just add an `identificationPredicate` to the mapping, specifying the exact entity:

```
    parentMapping.identificationPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity == %@", parentMapping.entity];
```